# Deploy Utility app as Windows Service NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows

Working on deploying an app with PKG for Windows as a service via Node-Windows.

I have my NodeWindows install and uninstall scripts, and I'm trying to use PKG to make those into Windows executables. PKG creates the `.exe` files, but when I run the file, it throws an error like the one below:

pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1226
      return wrapper.apply(this.exports, args);
                     ^

```
ReferenceError: svc is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\transient\installTransient2.js:0)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1226:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1281:12)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:432:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:192:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:547:3
```

with my Node-windows script like this:

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

var scv = new Service({
  name: 'Transient2',
  description: 'Yet Another File Transfer Utility in NodeJS',
  script: 'server.js'
});

svc.on('install', () => {
  console.log('successfully installed');
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

I want to think that node-windows isn't getting packed into the Executable. According to PKG's documentation, it should "shim" in anything in a require statement, unless it's declared with a `path.join()` call.

How can I package my app in an installer that creates a service in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint is in the error - you have declared the variable name 'scv' instead of 'svc' on line 3 in your Node.js script.

This means that when you add the 'install' event handler on line 9 to 'svc' it cannot find that variable because it was misspelt. This is why you're receiving the ReferenceError described.

Comment: Oh gah. I need to get better at spotting those